# Generate subdivided triangle-strip cube?

Tags: math, opengl, geometry

I want to generate a cube where each face is divided into bits, like the following image:

http://img59.imageshack.us/img59/2504/gridcube165c3.jpg

Now, I can do this pretty simply if I'm just rendering quads, by just spacing vertices along each face plane at regular intervals, but my problem comes in when I want to turn the whole thing into a triangle strip. I've just got no idea how to unwrap it programmatically- is there some pattern to unwrapping that I'd follow?

I'm thinking of starting with the vertex at the top left corner as Row 0 Column 0 (R0C0), I'd want  (first triangle) R0C0, ROC1, R1C1, (second triangle) R0C0, R1C0, R1C1 and so forth, and then when I reach the end of a row I guess I'd use a degenerate triangle to move to the next row, and then when I reach the end of the face I'd do the same to start a new face.

My main problem is that I can't visualize the program loop that would do this. I can reason out which vertex comes next visually, which is how I worked out the order above, but when I try to think programmatically I just stare blankly.

Even worse, with the end product I want the generated cube to be UV-mapped with a simple cube-map unwrap (the kind that looks like a T or t).

I guess, really, the best solution would be to find a library that already does this for me.

Answer (score 1):

You could take a look at [Ignacio Castaño's 'Optimal Grid Rendering'](http://www.ludicon.com/castano/blog/2009/02/optimal-grid-rendering/) even though it's not triangle strips, it may inspire you.

Otherwise, you could use [NVTriStrip](http://www.nvidia.com/object/nvtristrip_library.html) library and be done with it.